# Оттягивая страницу вниз / вверх браузер оставляет пустое место

Tags: css, вёрстка, google-chrome, браузер, mac

Как запретить браузеру такое поведение:
Зажимаем кнопку мыши и тянем вниз и у сайта появляется вот такое пустое поле

[image: скриншот]

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, что должен помочь любой из следующих вариантов, но порверить не могу:

1. Убедиться, что body всегда по размеру экрана (и даже на полпикселя оттуда ничего не вылазиет)
2. Задать фон для body
3. Указать `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: auto`

Comment: Неа 1-потому что у меня лэндинг к примеру, 2-ое - потому что у футера цвет красный а у хедера белый, 3 - просто не подходит

Answer (score 0):

Подсотрел решение как сделано в https://web.telegram.org/#/im

```
body { overflow: hidden;}
```

Но только это работает если весь контент меньше 100vh